# Core Data: Is it possible to use custom function in group by

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

Is it possible to use custom function (strftime) in group by part when crafting NSFetchRequest in objective-c? The sql statements is perfectly valid in sqlite:

```
select date, count(*) from note group by strftime('%Y%m%d', date)
```

However, after a day of digging and trying various ways and solutions I came to the conclusion it's impossible to do it with core data in single sql fetch. I'm using NSFetchRequest with setPropertiesToGroupBy (iOS 5.0 only).

UPDATE. There's an [example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009939) for getting such behavior with core data provided by apple. However, I have enabled "-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1" for showing SQL performed by core data. It appears, core data is not performing my desired SQL. It just selects them all with a first sql query, and then loops through the groups performing multiple "SELEC .. WHERE ID IN ...." SQL queries. An excerpt from console:

```
2012-07-05 10:34:57.244 DateSectionTitles[1139:fb03] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK     FROM ZEVENT t0 ORDER BY t0.ZTIMESTAMP
2012-07-05 10:34:57.245 DateSectionTitles[1139:fb03] CoreData: annotation: sql   connection fetch time: 0.0010s
2012-07-05 10:34:57.246 DateSectionTitles[1139:fb03] CoreData: annotation: total fetch    execution time: 0.0015s for 52 rows.
2012-07-05 10:34:57.247 DateSectionTitles[1139:fb03] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZTIMESTAMP, t0.ZTITLE FROM ZEVENT t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK IN  (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)  ORDER BY t0.ZTIMESTAMP LIMIT 20
2012-07-05 10:34:57.248 DateSectionTitles[1139:fb03] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0012s
2012-07-05 10:34:57.249 DateSectionTitles[1139:fb03] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0022s for 20 rows.
2012-07-05 10:34:57.250 DateSectionTitles[1139:fb03] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZTIMESTAMP, t0.ZTITLE FROM ZEVENT t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK IN  (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)  ORDER BY t0.ZTIMESTAMP LIMIT 20
2012-07-05 10:34:57.281 DateSectionTitles[1139:fb03] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0303s
2012-07-05 10:34:57.281 DateSectionTitles[1139:fb03] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0310s for 20 rows.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. Assemble your `NSFetchedResultsController` similar to:

```
  NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController =
  [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
  managedObjectContext:someManagedObjectContext
  sectionNameKeyPath:@"yearOnly" // <== 
  cacheName:@"cacheAsneeded"];
```

Then inside your NSManagedObject class add a method to be used with `sectionNameKeyPath`

```
- (int)yearOnly { // 
   NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
   return [[cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:self.date] year];
}
```

The request will return the results grouped by the year so that each encountered year will become a section.

If you need a grouping by  month too, you might want to change the calendar components appropriately.

For the count(*) add an `NSExpression` to your fetchRequest:

```
 NSExpression * many = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"count:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"someAttribute"]]];
```

Comment: Thanks, will try. Have noticed, NSFetchedResultsController often is used with delegation, is it mandatory or optional to set NSFetchedResultsController delegate? Can I use it the same way as NSFetchRequest?

Comment: The delegate is optional. See the documentation: `An instance of NSFetchedResultsController uses methods in this protocol to notify its delegate that the controller’s fetch results have been changed due to an add, remove, move, or update operations.` For example in a UITableView you would use it to update the rows and section after the dataset has been modified