# How to implement a transient property on core data?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have this core data entity called Countries. This entity has a field called nameOfCountry that contains country names in english. I need to localize this to other languages, so I have created a transient property called nameOfCountryLocalized.

On the Countries class I am importing this category

**Countries+NameOfCountryLocalized.h**

```
#import "Countries.h"

@interface Countries (NameOfCountryLocalized)


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * nameOfCountryLocalized;


@end
```

**Countries+NameOfCountryLocalized.m**

```
#import "Countries+NameOfCountryLocalized.h"
#import "Countries.h"

@implementation Countries (NameOfCountryLocalized)

@dynamic nameOfCountryLocalized;


-(NSString *) nameOfCountryLocalized {
  [self willAccessValueForKey:@"nameOfCountryLocalized"];
  NSString *nameLocalized = NSLocalizedString(self.nomePais, nil);
  [self didAccessValueForKey:@"nameOfCountryLocalized"];
  return nomeLocalizado;
}

-(void)setNameOfCountryLocalized:(NSString *) nameLocalized {
  [self willChangeValueForKey:@"nameOfCountryLocalized"];
  [self setNomePaisLocalizado:];
  [self didChangeValueForKey:@"nameOfCountryLocalized"];
}

@end
```

when I try to access nameOfCountryLocalized using this from a tableViewController

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

  if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
  }


  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                 entityForName:@"Countries" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
  [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

  NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"nameOfCountryLocalized" ascending:YES];
  [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sort]];

  [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

  NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
  [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                      managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                        sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                 cacheName:@"Root"];

  _fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
  _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

  return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

I see this error:**keypath nameOfCountryLocalized not found in entity**

any clues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NSFetchedResultsController cannot **sort** by a transient property. The FRC applies the **sort** to the underlying SQL store. With a transient property the FRC can **group** results of a fetch into sections. This **group** is created by assigned the transient property to `sectionNameKeyPath`.

Pulling all entities into an array will become a pain once your data grows. The FRC does provide nice support for larger data sets and you don't really want to loose that.

You might be ok assuming that your users don't switch language very often. If that is the case I suggest you write the localized country name into the store as a "normal" property and the FRC can do the sort on that property. 
Although when a user does switch language then you would need to update all Country entities.

Comment: I solved that by using what you say on the last paragraph but if you can put in code what you say on the first paragraph would be nice to know this other form of doing that. Thanks.

Comment: For an example on how to group please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11331553/529243 The example over there is for grouping by year, i.e. a number (int). If you want to group by country or initial letter of the country name you would need to adopt the code in the "yearOnly" method.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Countries` class is not an entity. It is a class for an *individual object* in the database.

You really should rename it to `Country`, as it's incorrect to refer to `NSManagedObject` subclasses as plural. There's a reason Apple didn't name the class `NSManagedObjects`.

Because your property is added to individual objects but not the entities themselves, it is only available after objects have been fetched from the database. It cannot be used as part of fetching the objects.

You're going to need to fetch the results first (all of them) into an `NSArray` and then sort the objects by applying the `NSSortDescriptor` to the `NSArray`. You might want to do this by creating a wrapper class around `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Alternatively, put a `nameOfCountryLocalized` property in the actual database, with english values, and then if the user doesn't use english write to the database changing everything to the correct values. This would allow you to use `NSFetchedResultsController` exactly as you're trying to do now. I recommend this approach if your database is huge... but it's not, there are only a couple hundred countries in the world so performance is a total non-issue.

Comment: ok, but why can't I use a transient property? I imagine there is a way to do that using this kind of properties. But have not figured it out yet. As usual, the documentation provided by Apple is confuse.

Comment: Apple's documentation is not confusing, you are miss-understanding how Core Data works. Perhaps you need to go back to the basic Core Data documentation and re-learn everything from scratch. The code you wrote does not work because Core Data is not designed to be able to do what you're trying to do. You need to take a completely different approach, which I highlighted in my answer.